# Query Filter Django

Tags: python, django, filter

I want to call `nilai` into a table in my template. This is my model:

```
class AlternatifJalur(models.Model):
    nama = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nama

class KriteriaJalur(models.Model):
    TIPE_KRITERIA_CHOICES = (
        ('benefit', 'Benefit'),
        ('cost', 'Cost'),
    )
    nama = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bobot = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 20, decimal_places = 2)
    keterangan = models.TextField()
    tipe = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TIPE_KRITERIA_CHOICES, default='Benefit')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nama

class Matriks(models.Model):
    kriteria = models.ForeignKey(KriteriaJalur)
    alternatif = models.ForeignKey(AlternatifJalur)
    nilai = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 20, decimal_places = 2)

    def nilai_float(self):
        return float(self.nilai)
```

This is my view :

```
def index(request):
    kriteria = KriteriaJalur.objects.all()
    alternatif = AlternatifJalur.objects.all()
    matriks = Matriks.objects.all()
    krite = KriteriaJalur.objects.get(nama='Jarak')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"kriteria":kriteria, "alternatif":alternatif, "matriks":matriks})
```

How can I call `nilai` from the `Matriks` class in my model so that `kriteria` in my `Matriks` class is equal to `nama` in my `kriteria` class and `alternatif` in my `Matriks` class is equal to `nama` in my `alternatif` class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you may want to use [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and/or [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) in order to filter your `matriks` obj based on `kriteria` `nama` and/or `alternatif` `nama`.

Change your `index` view to this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def index(request):
    kriteria = KriteriaJalur.objects.all()
    alternatif = AlternatifJalur.objects.all()

    # The below will contain all matriks whose kriteria nama is 'Kriteria A' AND alternatif nama is 'Jalur A'
    matriks = Matriks.objects.filter(kriteria__nama='Kriteria A', alternatif__nama='Jalur A')

    # The below will contain all matriks whose kriteria nama is 'Kriteria A' OR alternatif nama is 'Jalur A'
    matriks = Matriks.objects.filter(Q(kriteria__nama='Kriteria A') | Q(alternatif__nama='Jalur A'))

    krite = KriteriaJalur.objects.get(nama='Jarak')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"kriteria":kriteria, "alternatif":alternatif, "matriks":matriks})
```

How about this:

```
<!-- index.html -->

{% for matrik in matriks %}
    {{ matrik.nilai }}
{% endfor %}

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        {% for item in matriks %}
            <th>{{ item.kriteria.nama }} ({{ item.kriteria.bobot }} %)</th>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for item in alternatif %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.nama }}</td>
            {% for matrik in matriks %}
                <td>{{ item.JalurA }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i have try that, it will show all object in class matriks,
i want to filter it, i mean the `matrik.nilai` where  `kriteria.nama = 'Kriteria A'` and `alternatif.nama = 'Jalur A'`

Comment: Hmmm... I cannot understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you be more specific please? Maybe add an example, too?

Comment: thanks for your answer, its very helpfull. please forgive me about my english :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Please delete your own answer and edit your question with these data. Best regards

Comment: but wait, how to looping it ? my header table is all object of `kriteria`, and and i want to call 'for all object in matriks table, select object.nilai where object .kriteria.nama = kriteria.nama in the header and object.alternatif.nama = alternatif.nama in the left side of the table', look it in the picture i give before,

Comment: `<table class="table table-hover">
 <tr>
  <th>#</th>
  {% for item in kriteria %}
   <th>{{item.nama}} ({{item.bobot}} %)</th>
  {% endfor %}
  {% for item in alternatif %}
  <tr>
   <td>{{item.nama}}</td>
   {% for matrik in matriks %}
    <td>{{item.JalurA}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
 </tr>
</table>`

Comment: and if it possible, i want to query it directly from index.html

Comment: You cannot directly query it from the template. For that, you have to use a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) or [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags).

Answer (score 0):

[This is the table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orSdK.jpg)

in column 'Kriteria A' and field 'Jalur A', will be appear `matrik.nilai` where alternatif = 'Jalur A' and kriteria='Kriteria A'

@nik_m